# ValueError: Error when checking target: expected time_distributed_7 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (500, 18, 64)

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, keras

I cannot find the problem in my model. Here is my model summary:

```
________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_11 (InputLayer)        (None, 32, 100, 3)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_75 (Conv2D)           (None, 29, 97, 64)        3136      
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_23 (MaxPooling (None, 14, 48, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_76 (Conv2D)           (None, 10, 44, 256)       409856    
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_24 (MaxPooling (None, 5, 22, 256)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_77 (Conv2D)           (None, 5, 22, 512)        1180160   
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_78 (Conv2D)           (None, 5, 22, 1024)       4719616   
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_79 (Conv2D)           (None, 5, 22, 1024)       9438208   
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_80 (Conv2D)           (None, 5, 22, 3072)       3148800   
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_15 (Dropout)         (None, 5, 22, 3072)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_8 (Dense)              (None, 5, 22, 4096)       12587008  
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_16 (Dropout)         (None, 5, 22, 4096)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_81 (Conv2D)           (None, 5, 22, 64)         262208    
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_7 (TimeDist (None, 5, 22, 64)         4160      
=================================================================
Total params: 31,753,152
Trainable params: 31,753,152
Non-trainable params: 0
```

The model does not appear to be giving 3 dimensional output at any point. Please help me pinpoint the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Model's output shape: (any, 5, 22, 64)
- Y_train's output shape: (500, 18, 64)

These two shapes must match.

Comment: The problem was with the data flow. I fixed it.